# How do I disable the new Facebook ticker in the sidebar?

Tags: facebook

The [auto-refreshing status ticker](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=279345652077938) in the sidebar of the new Facebook layout is distracting. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Facebook doesn't allow you to disable the ticker - it only allows you to make it smaller:

> You can't close ticker, but you can make it smaller by moving the horizontal bar between ticker and chat. Slide the bar up to hide ticker and make your chat list longer. Pull the bar down to show more of the ticker and hide chat.

From the Facebook [help page](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=168035603275839).

However, you can install a Greasemonkey script, or Chrome extension to hide it:

- [**Facebook Ticker Remover** Greasemonkey script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/113593);
- [**Hide Facebook SideBar Ticker** Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ldfdjdnohanpkljbgeipdoeiefheaefp).

---

UPDATED: As per Kered Negah's answer below, Facebook have implemented a Hide Ticker / Show Ticker function. Fantastic!

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/31049/7932

Answer (score 6):

If you have an ad-blocking extension, you can add these to the manually edited list:

```
www.facebook.com##[id="pagelet_rhc_ticker"]
www.facebook.com##[id="pagelet_ticker"]
```

Works equally well in Firefox and Chrome.

This other Chrome extension (aptly named [Unannoying Facebook](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pflphkbajimngabpbfbhkikplpdaohoe)) does this for you, and also removes the hovering bar on the top, if that bothers you for some reason.

(via [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5842578/how-to-kill-the-facebook-news-ticker))

Answer (score 4):

- [Hide Facebook SideBar Ticker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ldfdjdnohanpkljbgeipdoeiefheaefp?hl=en-GB) is a Chrome extension that only hides the side bar.
- [Better Facebook](http://betterfacebook.net/) is a powerful browser extension that gives you a lot of control over your facebook feed look, including hiding the sidebar.

Answer (score 4):

The question was how to get rid of the Ticker, not how to get rid of the sidebar. You can click on the "Hide Ticker" arrow at the top right of the sidebar and it disappears completely. You can see it again by clicking on "Show Ticker" in the spot where "Hide Ticker" was before.

Comment: That's great. Do you know when they introduced that feature? I haven't seen it before. UPDATE: looks like it was back in February: http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57369750-285/how-to-hide-the-facebook-ticker-without-a-browser-extension/